# XSS and XXE payload in XML attributes value

Tags: xss, xxe

I am testing web application with functionality of file upload. The only possible file format is XML. The content of the file saved in XML attributes is then presented on the separate page.

For example XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Request xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1.0">
<Body CaseId="Test/123656">
    <person gender="female">
    <note date="2008-01-10">
</Body>
</Request>
```

The value of CaseID, gender and date is than presented on another page. 
Is it possible to send somehow XSS payload in attribute value if web application blocks "<"?
I would like to test also XXE,
is it possible to reference to external entity in attribute value?

Comment: it depends on how the data is displayed. you can use attrib events to own instead of script tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML Parsers usually interpret Unicode so you could use the format `\u00HH` and bypass validations for `<>`,for example:

```
\u003Cscript\u003Ealert(1);\u003C/script\u003E
```

When XML Parser read the data structure to show on view, then it interprets the Unicode Characters and the result is the following:

```
<script>alert(1);</script>
```

I hope this information helps you.